# Resizing Ubuntu ext4 partition using Gparted live dvd fails

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to shrink my ext4 ubuntu partition using a gparted live dvd by 50 gb for a windows NTFS partition. It's failing as shown below:

[image: error]

My problem is different from the other one because I've already tried to shrink it, but I get a certain error.

Here is the output of e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1:

```
    e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
    Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
    Pass 2: Checking directory structure
    Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
    Pass 4: Checking reference counts
    Pass 5: Checking group summary information
    /dev/sda1: 661890/38690816 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 86694031/154733568 blocks
```

[After trying @heynnema's solution, more blocks were completed but I still got the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ9Mo.png)

Okay so on a whim I shrunk it by 10 GB and it worked. I did it 4 more times and now have a 50 GB ntfs drive, so the issue is solved. Thanks.

Comment: That partition (sda1) seems to be mounted as root. Are you sure you are using the live dvd?

Comment: I know, I just took that screenshot to show you what the filesystem looks like. That screenshot is not from the live dvd. But it's identical other than the locks.

Comment: No, I know _how_ to start the process, but I'm stumped about why it doesn't complete it.

Comment: @Pilot6 this question is not a duplicate. The user knows how to use gparted, but is having error messages during a resize. I'm still working with the user to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the partition you want to resize then first try to "unmount". After that you should be able to resize that partition.

For your issue: The partition you are trying to resize needs to be fixed first. Do as it says on that error message please. You should be able to resize after fixing the file system.

Comment: No, on the live dvd it's already unmounted. It goes through the process and _then_ fails.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give specific details on that "fail". An error message, etc.

Comment: It's in the screenshot I put in the edit

Comment: Lol yes, I saw and edited the answer above. Your sda1 seems to be defective. You need to fix that first. That command on the error message should fix it.

Comment: I tried running the command and it did not fix it.

Comment: So there is something else. Do we have a clue from the output of that terminal command?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix some possible filesystem corruption on /dev/sda1.

You need to boot your Ubuntu using `Advanced Options`, then `Recovery Mode`, then choose `root access`. Once there, type:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

**Run this command more than once if there are errors.**

After that, boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, and start gparted. You should be able to resize and create your partitions now. **Since you're installing Windows AFTER Ubuntu, you should do some research here on AskUbuntu on how to do that, 'cause there are some pitfalls.**

Comment: Okay so I did what you said and now when I run gparted and redo the shrink it relocates more blocks, but still gives me the same error. Should I repeat?

Comment: @CthulhuFhatgn OK, please edit your question to include a **current-window-only** screenshot of gparted of /dev/sda, without the error message blocking the view.